# Compare Date-Time Stamps

Tags: shell, unix

I am looking to write a shell script that will compare the time between two date-time stamps in the format:

```
2013-12-10 13:25:30.123
2013-12-10 13:25:31.123
```

I can split the date and time if required (as the comparison should never be more than one second - I am looking at a reporting rate), so I can format the time as `13:25:30.123` / `13:25:31.123`.

Comment: What do you mean by compare?? giving the greatest or least or difference???

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Do you just need to select the newest / oldest one? Do you need the time difference? ...

Comment: I am looking to find the time difference between the two stamps.  Sorry I appreciate that I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Not a duplicate question - I am looking for the time accuracy down to milliseconds.

Comment: Still looks like a duplicate, just not an exact one. Solving for millisecond instead of hour, the method to solution is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just find the newer (or older) of the two timestamps, you could just use a string comparison operator:

```
time1="2013-12-10 13:25:30.123"
time2="2013-12-10 13:25:31.123"

if [ "$time1" > "$time2" ]; then
    echo "the 2nd timestamp is newer"
else
    echo "the 1st timestamp is newer"
fi
```

And, to find the time difference (tested):

```
ns1=$(date --date "$time1" +%s%N)
ns2=$(date --date "$time2" +%s%N)
echo "the difference in seconds is:" `bc <<< "scale=3; ($ns2 - $ns1) / 1000000000"` "seconds"
```

Which, in your case prints

```
the difference in seconds is: 1.000 seconds
```

Comment: Mega - I like this!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Convert them into timestamps before comparing:

```
if [ $(date -d "2013-12-10 13:25:31.123" +%s) -gt $(date -d "2013-12-10 13:25:30.123" +%s) ]; then
  echo "blub";
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl using the included Time::Piece library:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -nE '
    BEGIN {
        $, = "\t";
        sub to_seconds {
            my ($dt, $frac) = (shift =~ /(.*)(\.\d*)$/);
            return(Time::Piece->strptime($dt, "%Y-%m-%d %T")->epoch + $frac);
        }
    }
    if ($. > 1) {
        $a = to_seconds($_); 
        $b = to_seconds($prev); 
        say $a, $b, $a-$b
    } 
    $prev = $_
'<<END
2013-12-10 13:25:30.123
2013-12-10 13:25:31.123
2013-12-10 13:25:42.042
END
```

```
1386681931.123  1386681930.123  1
1386681942.042  1386681931.123  10.9190001487732
```